# Take mail ID by pressing a button in googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, r-googlesheets

Can someone suggest me a Google Script that will make a button that will get the mail ID of the person and put it into a specified Google sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your script. Create a drawing like a button, via the little 3 dots you can assign it to a script, type: getEmail.

If the user is a gmail user it will append the value to the target sheet. If not then it opens a prompt where someone can enter the email.

```
function getEmail(){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("targetsheet"); // change to desire
  const userMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  if (userMail == null){
    targetSheet.appendRow(ui.prompt("Enter email").getResponseText());
  } else {
    targetSheet.appendRow([userMail]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(userMail=null)` is an assignment not a comparison.  If you would have saved it before you posted it you would have received an error.  Don't feel bad though I've done this plenty of times.

Comment: I understood everything but I don't the feature of drawing in gscript. Can u please elaborate more drawing.By the way thanks a million

Comment: If you want it to create a button for you then it will have to be on the dialog or sidebar.

Comment: @SukhwinderRahal go to your sheet --> insert --> Drawing --> Make a nice button ;) --> then in the corner when you hove over with your mouse you see little dots --> assign script --> type: getEmail // Note: the gmail users get a pop-up where they need to give premission.

Comment: I am getting error i.e. " Assignment to constant variables".

Comment: @SukhwinderRahal - see the updated answer, Remco mistyped comparison operator - if you used the `userMail = null`, then you tried to reassign the `userMail` variable when running `getEmail()`, hence the error

Comment: Yes, Finally this code works. Thanks a lot guys.  I would be highly thankful to you if you can guide me how to embed this button in my google site.

Comment: @SukhwinderRahal Please, accept Remco's answer if you found it useful. If you have a follow up question - post it as a separate one from this (just a note - please, be clear and show research effort before doing so)